# How can I make input mask like this --:--:--?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input-mask

I need to make input ask for numbers like that `--:--:--` => `99:99:99`. How can I make it without plugins and only using React?

I can't add the code because I have no idea how to make this with simple input:

```
<TextField
  defaultValue="00:00:00"
  className={classes.textField}
  value={time}
  onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
  inputProps={{
    step: 700,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: If you're trying to set time, why not use `<input type="time">`? eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: @JamesWhiteley time has 24h format, I need to make 99:59:59

Comment: @wefwefцуаefwef It lets you have hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @NoahCalland as I said before, I need to set 99:59:59, but time gives an opportunity to set 24h format

Comment: The code I use in my music player to take seconds and turn it into minutes and seconds is this: `new Date(song.currentTime * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)`. just replace song.currentTime with your input and it'll auto format to HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 1):

Can simply use 3   `<TextField/>` and make a layout around them either using tables or grids.
Then each input can be handled individually.